# Vertical align of minipage tcolorbox

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, tcolorbox

I'm trying to put two instances of `tcolorbox` side by side and to vertically align to the top. From other posts I have tried `minipage` with option `[t]` with this code

```
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=isabelline,colframe=antiquewhite!20!black,title=Boundary layer]
\footnotesize{0, no boundary-layer\\
1, YSU scheme\\
2, Mellor-Yamada-Janjic TKE\\
3, NCEP Global Forecast System}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=isabelline,colframe=antiquewhite!20!black,title=Surface physics]
\footnotesize{0, no surface temp prediction\\
1, thermal diffusion scheme\\
2, Unified Noah land-surface model\\
1, thermal diffusion scheme\\
2, Unified Noah land-surface model\\
1, thermal diffusion scheme\\
2, Unified Noah land-surface model\\
3, RUC land-surface model}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But the result is that they are bottom-aligned. What am I missing?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: `\footnotesize` does not have an argument, it is a font size switch only. And you don't need explicit `\\` , just leave an empty line

Comment: There's not any argument for footnotesize. 0 is the first character that has this font size.

Comment: No, you're stating `\footnotesize{0, no surface...}` ... this is like an argument. `\footnotesize` is sufficient. If you want to restrict the meaning of `\footnotesize` to some part of the text only, use it this way: `{\footnotesize foo bar}`, but apparently you wanted all to appear in that size...

Comment: A tip: If you have many of such boxes, defining a `\newtcolorbox` environment will be very effective -- it will prevent specifing the same options over and over again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the update for a special `tcolorbox` for such environments at the end of the answer.

Use `tcbraster` to align the box -- this provides a much cleaner interface for many setups with `tcolorbox`.

Say `\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,box valign=top]...\end{tcbraster}`, for example

Please note that only `tcolorbox` environments may appear in a raster.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster valign=top]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!70!yellow,colframe=white!20!black,title=Boundary layer]
\footnotesize 0, no boundary-layer

1, YSU scheme

2, Mellor-Yamada-Janjic TKE

3, NCEP Global Forecast System
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!70!yellow,colframe=white!20!black,title=Surface physics]
\footnotesize 0, no surface temp prediction 

1, thermal diffusion scheme

2, Unified Noah land-surface model

1, thermal diffusion scheme

2, Unified Noah land-surface model

1, thermal diffusion scheme

2, Unified Noah land-surface model

3, RUC land-surface model
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** with special `tcolorbox` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{somebox}[1][]{%
  colback=white!70!yellow,
  colframe=white!20!black,
  #1%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster valign=top,fontupper=\footnotesize]
\begin{somebox}[title=Boundary layer]
0, no boundary-layer

1, YSU scheme

2, Mellor-Yamada-Janjic TKE

3, NCEP Global Forecast System
\end{somebox}
\begin{somebox}[title=Surface physics]
0, no surface temp prediction 

1, thermal diffusion scheme

2, Unified Noah land-surface model

1, thermal diffusion scheme

2, Unified Noah land-surface model

1, thermal diffusion scheme

2, Unified Noah land-surface model

3, RUC land-surface model
\end{somebox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `fontupper=\footnotesize` would be even easier...

Comment: `box align=top` could be also a valid alternative. It doesn't need a `raster` and, I think, it's easier to adjust the width of boxes when they don't occupy the whole line or they are not equal.

Comment: @Ignasi: But that's the point: You have to manually adjust the width, of course `box align=top` works for single boxes then.

Comment: for single boxes and with `nobeforeafter` for pairs of boxes like in this case (see pag 77. example at bottom of page).

Comment: @Ignasi: Sorry, singles boxes = boxes that are not inside a raster, i.e. not grouped.

Answer (score 6):

Here, I used the `\belowbaseline` feature of `stackengine` to place each `minipage` a value of `-\ht\strutbox` below the baseline, so that it acts like a `[t]` aligned box.  I added, as a test, "See baseline" text before the first box, so as to discern the rendered alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor,stackengine}
\begin{document}
See baseline\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!3,colframe=yellow!20!black,title=Boundary layer]
\footnotesize{0, no boundary-layer\\
1, YSU scheme\\
2, Mellor-Yamada-Janjic TKE\\
3, NCEP Global Forecast System}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}}
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!3,colframe=yellow!20!black,title=Surface physics]
\footnotesize{0, no surface temp prediction\\
1, thermal diffusion scheme\\
2, Unified Noah land-surface model\\
1, thermal diffusion scheme\\
2, Unified Noah land-surface model\\
1, thermal diffusion scheme\\
2, Unified Noah land-surface model\\
3, RUC land-surface model}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your obsession of this 'strange' `stackengine` package is becoming very obvious;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As noted before, if the only tool in your toolbox is a hammer, pretty soon every problem starts looking like a nail.

Comment: `tcolorbox` is a Swiss Army Knife... not usable everywhere, but very often ... and I live only 100km away from the border to Switzerland ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm thinking of renaming the package `OPositive` (`;^)`) to remind users that it is the universal-donor package that any code can receive.  Hmmm. maybe `RubeGoldberg` would be more appropriate??