# Placing two tcolorboxes side by side

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

I am working on a latex document that uses `tcolorboxes` and I want to place two different `tcolorboxes` side by side. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I found that using `minipage` we can achieve this. This is demonstrated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351886/vertical-align-of-minipage-tcolorbox).

Comment: You could use `tcbraster`. But please post a MWE to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @TeXnician Hi, so far I tried different widths for the boxes, but they did not work. How will I be able to use `tcbraster`?

Comment: A minipage is the wrong way to go here. Use tcbraster as recommended already.... look into the manual please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the `tcbraster` way to place two (or more?) boxes side by side, by using the `tcbraster` environment and `raster columns=2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height]
\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter, title=box 1]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter, title=box 2]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**Update** with more options:

Any option, that is not specific to the `raster` library will be handed over to the rastered `tcolorbox` environments, as such, those options have not to be specified each time, but only once in the raster setup.

Use `raster column skip` to increase the horizontal gap between the boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height,nobeforeafter,raster column skip=2cm]
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=box 1]
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=box 2]
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.475\textwidth, nobeforeafter, title=box 1]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}\hfill
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.475\textwidth, nobeforeafter, title=box 2]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: But, there's a small issue: When I try a third `tcolorbox` after the two `tcolorboxes` that you mentioned that I want to place on a different line, it gets shifted to the left of the margin by a few inches, i.e., the first `tcolorbox` is vertically slightly to the right of the third one. How will get the left sides of both of them to be vertically aligned?

Comment: @Python_user for more than two boxes, use a `tcbraster` like in Christian's answer.