# How to arrange color box vertically parallel to each other in a color box?

Tags: tcolorbox

I have tried the following code. I want color box "C" should be vertically parallel to color box "A".

```
\documentclass\[border=10pt\]{standalone}
\usepackage\[most\]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{GreenBox}\[2\]\[\]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = green!5!white,
   colframe  = green!75!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Huge\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}

\newtcolorbox{BlueBox}\[2\]\[\]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = blue!5!white,
   colframe  = blue!65!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Large\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}
 

\begin{GreenBox}\[width=11cm, remember as=box1, nobeforeafter\]{ABC}

  \begin{BlueBox}\[width=5cm, remember as=box11, nobeforeafter\]{A}
  Some Text here.
  \end{BlueBox}
  
  \hfill
  
  \begin{BlueBox}\[width=5cm, remember as=box12, nobeforeafter\]{B}
  \end{BlueBox}
  
  \hfill
  
  \begin{BlueBox}\[width=5cm, remember as=box13, nobeforeafter\]{C}
  \end{BlueBox}

  
\end{GreenBox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is not cmpilable since it contains all the `\ `s before `[` and `]`. To make it compilable, replace all occurences of `\[` with `[` and `\]` with `]`.

Comment: using `tcbraster` will get the result desired -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351886/vertical-align-of-minipage-tcolorbox

Comment: What exactly does " vertically parallel" mean here? In your question you describe the relative position of the boxes "A" and "C", but what about box "B"? Where should this box be placed? Probably adding a sketch of the expected output would help? Please also be aware that two of the `5cm` wide blue boxes won't fit side by side into an `11cm` wide green box. Could you alter the widths of the boxes or are they fixed? If so, you could change the inner margins of the green box. instead.

Comment: @MuhammadAliBaig -- added the following code `\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster valign=top]` -- please see the answer below -- you can choose the appropriate placement by changing `raster valign=top` or `raster valign =center`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `raster valign=center`

[image]

with `raster valign=top`

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \newtcolorbox{GreenBox}[2][]{%
        enhanced,
        colback   = green!5!white,
        colframe  = green!75!black, 
        arc       = 4mm, 
        outer arc = 1mm, 
        fonttitle = \Huge\slshape\textbf,
        center title, 
        title     = #2,
        #1}
    
    \newtcolorbox{BlueBox}[2][]{%
        enhanced,
        colback   = blue!5!white,
        colframe  = blue!65!black, 
        arc       = 4mm, 
        outer arc = 1mm, 
        fonttitle = \Large\slshape\textbf,
        center title, 
        title     = #2,
        #1}
    
    
    \begin{GreenBox}[width=11cm, remember as=box1, nobeforeafter,]{ABC}
        \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster valign=top]%<------------added
            
        \begin{BlueBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box11, nobeforeafter]{A}
            Some Text here.
        \end{BlueBox}
        \begin{BlueBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box12, nobeforeafter]{B}
        \end{BlueBox}
        \begin{BlueBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box13, nobeforeafter]{C}
        \end{BlueBox}
        \end{tcbraster}
    \end{GreenBox}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for `tcbraster` in this case. The problem comes from the empty lines between boxes and `\hfill`. An empty line in LaTeX means to start a newparagraph, therefore `nobeforeafter` option and `\hfill` have no effect. Just delete these empty lines or comment out, you get boxes A and B one beside the other.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{GreenBox}[2][]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = green!5!white,
   colframe  = green!75!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Huge\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}

\newtcolorbox{BlueBox}[2][]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = blue!5!white,
   colframe  = blue!65!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Large\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}
 

\begin{GreenBox}[width=11cm, remember as=box1, nobeforeafter]{ABC}

  \begin{BlueBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box11, nobeforeafter]{A}
  Some Text here.
  \end{BlueBox}
  %
  \hfill
  %
  \begin{BlueBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box12, nobeforeafter]{B}
  \end{BlueBox}
    
  \begin{BlueBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box13, nobeforeafter]{C}
  \end{BlueBox}
\end{GreenBox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: After my answer I've seen that OP wants box C beside box B and I did it wrong. The best solution could be to declare box C just after box A and box B after them. Another solution could be to use a multi column environment inside the tcolorbox.

Comment: in such a case can we change the alignement of A and B

Comment: @jsbibra you can decide vertical align with `box align` option. Another solution could be to use an `equal height group`. This way there is no need to decide the vertical align format.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following codes. But I have an issue the width of the boxes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0em}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{GreenBox}[2][]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = green!5!white,
   colframe  = green!75!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Huge\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}

\newtcolorbox{BlueBox}[2][]{%
   enhanced,
   colback   = blue!5!white,
   colframe  = blue!65!black, 
   arc       = 4mm, 
   outer arc = 1mm, 
   fonttitle = \Large\slshape\textbf,
   center title, 
   title     = #2,
   #1}

 \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster valign=center] 

\begin{GreenBox}[width=10cm, remember as=box1, nobeforeafter]{Objectives 1}

 \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1, raster valign=center] 
  
  \begin{BlueBox}[width=10cm, remember as=box14, nobeforeafter]{Objective 1.1}
  Some text here.
    \end{BlueBox}
  \end{tcbraster}
  \end{GreenBox}
  \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box2, nobeforeafter]{Objective 2}
Some text here.
\end{GreenBox}
  \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box3, nobeforeafter]{Objective 3}
Some text here
\end{GreenBox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to ask a new question to attract a larger audience